# Locating shared library libOS.so

Tags: linux, centos, shared-libraries, yum, rhel

I have downloaded a script that used libOS.so, bit I don't have it on CemtOS 6.7 and can't find any info on which software package uses libOS.so

Can anyone tell me which package includes libOS.so?

Comment: What are requirements to the script?
Cannot libOS.so be related to library operating system for Linux (LibOS):
https://lwn.net/Articles/637658/

Comment: https://www.rpmfind.net/linux/RPM/fedora/24/x86_64/c/coin-or-OS-devel-2.10.1-1.fc24.i686.html

Answer (score 0):

yum provides "*libOS.so*"

hope it will help you .